# Configure GC in Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working on Azure databricks. As part performance tuning one suggestion in spark documentation is to change GC settings in Spark.

[image]

Any idea where I can change this setting in Azure databricks?

Link for performance tuning:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set these in the cluster configuration

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -XX:+G1HeapRegionSize
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -XX:+G1HeapRegionSize
```